# How do I install Adobe Acrobat reader without the download manager?

Tags: adobe-reader

How do I install Adobe Acrobat reader without the download manager?

Comment: I have been asking myself the same question many times.  Adobe used to have acrobat available as a standalone download on their FTP site, but it seems they have pulled it.

Comment: My problem is that 'download manager' doesn't work through the corporate firewall.  The FTP site does the trick!

Comment: Very inane to password protect the download. It is blocked by corporate firewalls and searching google leads to non-adobe software

Answer (score 15):

You can download the standalone installations of many Adobe products from their FTP site - ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/.

For Acrobat Reader specifically you can download 10.0.1 for Windows (the current latest) here - ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/win/10.x/10.0.1/en_US/AdbeRdr1001_en_US.exe

Comment: Current/future full versions can be found below ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/
You'll be able choose your OS from there and then version.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer [SumatraPDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) over the others it is extremely lightweight and free. I did use Foxit in the past but it became to bloated for me.

Comment: I use Sumatra for years now and it is exactly what everyone needs: Open and View PDFs very fast. I can really recommend it and you can forget the Adobe Reader.

Comment: Whilst true, I'm not sure suggesting an alternative reader is that helpful. I would expect someone on superuser know adobe isn't the only pdf viewer in the world. This would probably merit a comment but not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Program EXE:
ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/win/11.x/11.0.10/en_US/AdbeRdr11010_en_US.exe

Update to v11.0.12:
ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/win/11.x/11.0.12/misc/

Comment: Why not just point out that http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?product=1&platform=Windows always has a link to the latest version (as well as archive versions). In any case you need to provide more information than just a link or your answer wil be closed.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: @DavidPostill - I need a full installer to put on a non-Internet-connected PC.  And I don't really fit the bill for a re-distributor...  The .com/support/downloads link gives you a stub application that serves as a downloader/installer...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. If you just want to read PDFs you could get something like [Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/reader/).

(I am not affiliated with Foxit)

Answer (score 0):

Current/future full versions can be found below ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/
You'll be able choose your OS from there and then version.

(They make a lot of software and starting at the top of 'ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe' can get you side-tracked by a link to 'acrobatreader' which has versions up to around v5.0)

Comment: This might be more appropriate as a comment on edusysadmin's answer since it's more of an improvement to that answer than a different solution.